# tightest upper bound of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a sequence $S=\{s_i\}^n_i$, where $s_i$ are integers s.t $\sum^n_{i=0}s_i\neq 0$.

Is it possible to find a polynomial upper bound on the ratio: $$\left|\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}i\cdot s_i}{\sum^n_{i=0}s_i}\right|$$

Comment: The denominator can be zero, indeed, that can happen infinitely often, so the quotient won't even be defined.

Comment: To say they are integers is to say nothing. Is there anything else known, however unimportant, by any chance? Maybe they are _positive_ integers? That would change a lot.

Comment: No, they can be negative.

Comment: Then the ratio can be anything. Or wait, maybe there is an upper bound on $|s_i|$?

Comment: A loose one, maybe $C^n$.

Comment: I note that after I posted my earlier comment, the question was edited to rule out division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $\|s\|_\infty = \max_i |s_i|$, you have the trivial upper bound
$$
\left|\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}i\cdot s_i}{\sum^n_{i=0}s_i}\right| \leq \left|\sum^n_{i=1}i\cdot s_i\right| \leq n^2\|s\|_\infty.
$$
Now let's look at a lower bound. Suppose for simplicity that $n$ is even, pick some $\|s\|_\infty$, and let
$$
s_i = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if $i = 0$,}\\
-\|s\|_\infty &\text{if $1 \leq i \leq \frac n2$,}\\
\|s\|_\infty &\text{if $\frac n2 < i \leq n$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\left|\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}i\cdot s_i}{\sum^n_{i=0}s_i}\right| = \|s\|_\infty \left(\sum_{i=n/2+ 1}^n i - \sum_{i = 1}^{n/2}i\right) = \|s\|_\infty \left(\frac n2\right)^2 = \frac14 \|s\|_\infty n^2.
$$
This shows that up to a constant, this upper bound is the best you can do.

Comment: Why is it not possible to get a different configuration of $s_i$ to get a higher ratio?

Comment: You can go higher, just no higher than four times as high. (In fact I don't think you can go meaningfully higher at all, but I didn't prove that.)